# Passing in source database as command line argument

Tags: postgresql, pgsync

I am working at something where i have to create a shell script to sync databases between source and target. the target is always localhost:<db_name> (db_name can change). The source db can change.

I am using `pgsync` to the sync between target and source. The way i am structuring my script is to start a shell script which gives option which db to sync. based on selection, build the source url and pass it to `pgsync` for `from` attribute.

I have been trying to find `pgsync` documentation and couldn't find a way how can i pass it the `from` value. is it possible

Comment: Can you share the script and what you have tried

Comment: @EmAe : So this question is about how to invoke `pgsync`, and not about writing a bash script - correct? In this case, please post this at [su].